# Function created with compilation error

Tags: sql, function, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION late_return_fee
(number_of_books IN NUMBER, days_of_late_return IN NUMBER)
RETURN DEC(4, 2)
IS
fee DEC(4,2);   
BEGIN
fee := number_of_books *(days_of_late_return*0.50);
RETURN fee;
END;
/
```

but it come out error : Function created with compilation error. Please Help

Comment: Do `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify any constraint for a function's return value, so you need to remove the `(4,2)` from that clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION late_return_fee
(number_of_books IN NUMBER, days_of_late_return IN NUMBER)
RETURN DEC  -- note no size constraint
IS
fee DEC(4,2);   
BEGIN
fee := number_of_books *(days_of_late_return*0.50);
RETURN fee;
END;
/

Function LATE_RETURN_FEE compiled

show errors

No errors.
```

Not sure why you'd use `DEC[IMAL]` here instead of `NUMBER` and `NUMBER(4,2)`.